# placement of 'unfortunately'

Tags: word-usage

What is the best placement of the word *unfortunately in the following sentence* -
1) "...though you must, unfortunately, be online for this feature to work."
2) "...though you must be online for this feature to work, unfortunately."

Also are the commas correctly used?

Comment: Might come best after _though_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland please can you illustrate why it should be placed in that position over any other.

Comment: Because it alerts the reader to the bad news that follows.

Comment: First of all, it's not a sentence, but a sentence fragment.  I suggest that filling in the ellipsis would help potential answerers.  For what it's worth, the word "unfortunately" could also come before "though," which would require a comma after "though" and "unfortunately."  "Unfortunately" could also come after "online."  In the absence of the words you've  elided, however, I agree with Barrie England.  Why?  Because it sounds better there!

Comment: Why don't you simply say 'Unfortunately you have to be on line for this feature to work'?.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose an option #4 that dispenses with "though" entirely:

"Unfortunately, you must be online for this feature to work."

I don't see that "though" really adds anything, though there is a lack of context.

Comment: That's a good answer, dude.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably surmise, both are correct as to comma placement, but which usage is *best* is rather subjective, depending upon what you want to emphasize.

I would say that usage #1 tends to emphasize the unfortunatality of the need for being online, and usage #2 emphasizes it less.  Taking @BarrieEngland's suggestion as usage #3, I would judge it as having the least emphasis of the unfortunatality among the three choices, namely because that placement seems to interrupt the flow of the phrase the least.

So, the best way to express the unfortunate need for being online, without making a big deal out of it, is to follow @BarrieEngland's suggestion...

3) "...though unfortunately you must be online for this feature to work."

And this version doesn't require commas.

Comment: How about that cool word "unfortunatality "?  Dictionary.com doesn't think it's a word, but "unfortunateness" is a word.  I like *my* new invention better, alas.